# How to deploy an Angular 2 App using Firebase hosting?

Tags: angular, firebase-hosting

I want to know the steps necessary to deploy a simple Angular 2 Application using Firebase-hosting.

Comment: You should read the docs.  If you have a specific error or question, please elaborate. https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/

Comment: I did read the docs but found nothing specific to Angular 2.

Comment: Here's a more detailed explanation of the steps: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart

Comment: No special steps should be needed for deploying an Angular 2 application on Firebase Hosting. Did you run into problems?

Comment: Was looking for something more Angular 2 oriented. Going through the steps right now.

Answer (score 8):

These are the steps:

```
1) npm install -g firebase-tools
```

This will install firebase CLI that we will use in the following steps.

> Firebase CLI requires Node.js version 0.10.0 or greater.

```
2) firebase init
```

**Project setup**

This will trigger Firebase project setup and store all settings in a local file `firebase.json`.

- *? What Firebase CLI features do you want to setup for this folder?* Make sure [Hosting: Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting sites] is checked and press INTRO.
- *? What Firebase project do you want to associate as default?* Choose [create a new project]

**Hosting setup**

- *? What do you want to use as your public directory?*
  You need to choose the (build) folder for your Angular 2 Application. Default is (public).
- *? Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)?* Answer Yes.

> Note: anything under this folder will be served as static assets.

```
4) You need to go to (https://console.firebase.google.com) to create a new Project.
```

- Click on (CREATE NEW PROJECT).
- Pick up a cool name for your project and select a Country/region. Eg: United Kingdom.

Your project name will look something like `cool-f5b0d`.

```
5) firebase use --add
```

Pick up the project you just created.

- *? Which project do you want to add?* Choose the new project you created.
- *? What alias do you want to use for this project?* You can use an alias for easy reference

`6) firebase deploy`

This will deploy your asset folder set up during step 2. Make sure this matches the (build) folder for your Angular 2 Application.

Comment: Why does an Angular2 app need to answer Yes to "Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)?"

Comment: this is so when you write a random url it's redirected to index.html and avoids showing 404 for a lot of cases

Answer (score 3):

Below steps shows How to deploy Angular 2 project to firebase hosting:

1. Build your project, for example in webstorm inside terminal run command:

   **pub build**

The command will run and create a **build/web** directory which include your compiled project

2. In your command line initialize your firebase project by run:

   **firebase init**

follow the instructions until you reach below question:

```
What do you want to use as your public directory?
```

3. Here you've to give the full path of your project directory
   build/web starting from *home directory*. In windows for example the home directory is:

   c:\users\YOU-USER-DIRECTORY

so if your project available in *c:\users\YOU-USER-DIRECTORY\projects\MyProject*, then give below directory to firebase:

```
projects/MyProject/build/web
```

make sure to use **front slash** **/** not backslash \

4. After finishing rest firebase questions, run:

   **firebase deploy**

it will take some time to upload all project files, then **enjoy!**

Answer (score 3):

Do Create a project with Angular CLI first. Get More info here https://cli.angular.io/

**Step 1: Build your App**

Run the below cmd to build

```
ng build --prod
```

**Step 2: Create FireBase project and Install Firebase CLI**

Open the Firebase console at https://console.firebase.google.com/ and create a new Firebase project.

To install the Firebase command line tools run:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

**Step 3: Deploy to FireBase**

Run the below firebase cmd to login:

```
firebase login
```

It will open the browser and ask you for authentication. Login with your Firebase account. There after you can close the browser window. On the command line you'll receive the message that the login has been performed successfully.

Now run the below cmd:

```
firebase init
```

First of all you're being asked which of the Firebase client features you want to use. You should select the option Hosting: Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting site. Next the Firebase client will ask which folder to use for deployment. Type in **dist**. That is important because that is the location where our production build is stored.

Next the question is ask if this app is a single page app and if it should rewrite all URLs to index.html. In our case we need to answer yes.

Last question is if Firebase should over write file index.html. The answer to that question is no.

Now, Run the below cmd to deploy:

```
firebase deploy
```

Firebase will provide a **URL** which you can use to access your application online.

Comment: I had followed your steps exactly and on the URL the firebases provided I see only a Message saying                                                                               Welcome

Firebase Hosting Setup Complete

You're seeing this because you've successfully setup Firebase Hosting. Now it's time to go build something extraordinary!

OPEN HOSTING DOCUMENTATION                                                              can u plz help??

Comment: It seems your Index.html file has been replaced. During the process of firebase init, type N, when the question "File dist/index.html already exists. Overwrite?".

Answer (score 1):

**Below is the complete steps which I have followed and hosted my website successfully.**
1. First of all you need to create a project/app in firebase console([Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/)).

After creating app/project you will see like myfirstfbhosting-b0ae......
Now you are ready to install tools to upload the files of your website

2. Install the Firebase CLI

The Firebase CLI (Command Line Interface) requires Node.js and npm, which can both be installed by following the instructions on [Node.js software](https://nodejs.org/). Installing Node.js also installs npm.

The Firebase CLI requires Node.js version 0.10.0 or greater.
Once you have Node.js and npm installed, you can install the Firebase CLI via npm:

3. After installing Firebase CLI with npm

Run the command - "npm install -g firebase-tools" in cmd
This installs the globally available firebase command. To update to the latest version, simply re-run the same command.

4. Initialize your app
   Once you've chosen the Firebase app you'd like to deploy, cd into your project directory like D:/pradeep/website/
   and run the command: "firebase init" in cmd

Running the firebase init command you will see that a "firebase.json" file is created in the root of your project (D:/pradeep/website/) 
Important Note: Open firebase.json in notepad, If it is {} then edit it to {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "."
  }
} and save.

One more thing index.html file along with other files must be in same directory(D:/pradeep/website/)

5. Select the app which is created in firebase console.
   If you have created more than 1 app there then select any one app by 
   type in cmd -   "firebase list" - all apps list will be shown.
   then - "firebase use "
   and then
6. Deploy your website
   To deploy your website simply run:
   write in cmd -"firebase deploy"

And finally Your app will be deployed to the domain .firebaseapp.com

Answer (score 0):

Angular has a cool feature on integrating with Firebase by adding the @angular/fire schematics using ng add @angular/fire.

Straight from Angular documentation. For step 5, use outputPath under build in angular.json
Hosting an Angular app on Firebase
One of the easiest ways to get your site live is to host it using Firebase.

1. Sign up for a firebase account on Firebase.
2. Create a new project, giving it any name you like on firebase itself.
3. Add the @angular/fire schematics that will handle your deployment using ng add @angular/fire.
4. Connect your CLI to your Firebase account and initialize the connection to your project using firebase login and firebase init.
5. Follow the prompts to select the Firebase project you are creating for hosting.
   o   Select the Hosting option on the first prompt.
   o   Select the project you previously created on Firebase.
   o   Select dist/my-project-name as the public directory.  (this is written in Angular.json  )
6. Deploy your application with ng deploy.
7. Once deployed, visit https://your-firebase-project-name.firebaseapp.com to see it live!

https://angular.io/start/start-deployment#hosting-an-angular-app-on-firebase