# Angular 4 firebase hosting project

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-hosting

I want to deploy my angular 4 project on Firebase
I had read this link [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38273130/how-to-deploy-an-angular-2-app-using-firebase-hosting)
..I followed all the steps ( build the project etc.. ) and Firebase gave me a url to see my deployed project.
However, on this link I see just this image.

How I am supposed to upload the project??
Is just the build folder enough to upload  the whole application or I need to do something more manually???
 [image]

Comment: You need to make sure the `public` field in your `firebase.json` is set to the build output directory compiled by Angular. Right now it looks like it's just the default `public` directory.

Comment: My  `firebase.json` currently is `"hosting": {
    "public": "dist",` and I selected to use dist folder as public directory when I   used firebase init command.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `@angular/cli` to build the project you'll want your `firebase.json` file to be set up in the following way (disregarding database and other rules):

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You want to be sure that the `firebase.json` file is at the same directory level as the `.angular-cli.json` and the built 'dist' folder generated by the cli.

The structure should look like this:

```
dist/
e2e/
src/
.angular-cli.json
firebase.json
```

Run `ng build --prod` then `firebase deploy` at the same level as `firebase.json` and on success go to the URL provided the command line message of `firebase-tools`. I'd do an "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" to clear the cache if you're using Chrome.

If you go to the firebase console for the project, in the **Hosting** dashboard, the number of files in the `/dist` folder should match the number of files listed the most recent entry of "Deployment History".

Hopefully that helps!