# Angular 4 and firebase not working

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2, firebase-hosting

I'm working on getting a static site I've made to run using Firebase.

But I have problems with the tutorials i've found..

Like this one: [Tutorial page](http://javasampleapproach.com/frontend/angular/how-to-integrate-firebase-with-angular-4)

Everything goes fine until i get to "III. Check Result" section..

I only get a blak white page with this source:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Virkplan</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

I have just copy&pasted from the site and changed my firebase details..

Why do this not work?

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://alligator.io/angular/deploying-angular-app-to-firebase/ I followed the same and was successful in deploying my Angular4 app on firebase. I faced some issues listed here: [Error deploying Angular application on Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46013826/error-deploying-angular-application-on-firebase) but was able to set it up manually.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I this is hosting only.. I want to get some database running and handle my data..